# H264_QSV will decode, VP9_QSV will not

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, ffmpeg, intel-graphics, codec

Yet another Intel Quick Sync (QSV) issue.

I've been using QSV enabled decoders, encoders, and filters for about a year, and mostly it works, at least for H264.  But, as others have reported, HEVC and VP9 have problems.  My latest is that I want to decode VP9 and encode H264.

Intel says vp9_qsv is a decoder as well as an encoder. My version of ffmpeg says it has it.

```
I:\Downloads>ffmpeg -hide_banner -h decoder=h264_qsv
Decoder h264_qsv [H264 video (Intel Quick Sync Video acceleration)]:
    General capabilities: dr1 delay avoidprobe hybrid
    Threading capabilities: none
    Supported hardware devices: qsv
    Supported pixel formats: nv12 p010le qsv
h264_qsv AVOptions:
  -async_depth       <int>        .D.V....... Internal parallelization depth, the higher the value the higher the latency. (from 1 to INT_MAX) (default 4)
  -gpu_copy          <int>        .D.V....... A GPU-accelerated copy between video and system memory (from 0 to 2) (default default)
     default         0            .D.V.......
     on              1            .D.V.......
     off             2            .D.V.......

I:\Downloads>ffmpeg -h decoder=vp9_qsv
ffmpeg version 4.4-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-lib
ml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --e
able-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --
nable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-
ibzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslan
 --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshin
 --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-l
bvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Decoder vp9_qsv [VP9 video (Intel Quick Sync Video acceleration)]:
    General capabilities: dr1 delay avoidprobe hybrid
    Threading capabilities: none
    Supported hardware devices: qsv
    Supported pixel formats: nv12 p010le qsv
vp9_qsv AVOptions:
  -async_depth       <int>        .D.V....... Internal parallelization depth, the higher the value the higher the latency. (from 1 to INT_MAX) (default 4)
  -gpu_copy          <int>        .D.V....... A GPU-accelerated copy between video and system memory (from 0 to 2) (default default)
     default         0            .D.V.......
     on              1            .D.V.......
     off             2            .D.V.......
```

If I do this when the input file is AVC / H264

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -err_detect aggressive -loglevel verbose -stats -benchmark ^
 -init_hw_device qsv:hw,child_device_type=qsv -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv  ^
 -vcodec h264_qsv -to 00:10:00.000 -i "h264_input_file.mkv" -strict normal ^
 -c:a aac -q:a 0.9  ^
 -vf "hwupload=extra_hw_frames=128,vpp_qsv=w=1696:h=954" ^
 -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryslow -q:v 32 -movflags +faststart ^
 "h264_output_file.mp4"
```

It works.  Verbose says the QSV decoders and encoders are working, GPU-Z says the gpu is busy, etc.  Sometimes the decoder chocks on the input because the QSV decoder is apparently very, very picky about what it can read, but the important point is that the h264_qsv decoder loads and runs.  I believe this very clearly shows that QSV is installed and working, since I can decode, filter, and encode using QSV enabled codecs and filters. But if I do the same thing with VP9 like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -err_detect aggressive -loglevel verbose -stats -benchmark ^
 -init_hw_device qsv:hw,child_device_type=qsv -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv  ^
 -vcodec vp9_qsv -to 00:10:00.000 -i "vp9_input_file.mkv" -strict normal ^
 -c:a aac -q:a 0.9  ^
 -vf "hwupload=extra_hw_frames=128,vpp_qsv=w=1696:h=954" ^
 -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryslow -q:v 32 -movflags +faststart ^
 "h264_output_file.mp4"
```

I get flooded with errors.

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -err_detect aggressive -loglevel verbose -stats -benchmark  -init_hw_device qsv:hw,child_device_type=qsv -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_
format qsv   -vcodec vp9_qsv -to 00:10:00.000 -i "VIEW 360： Taking a FLIRT to the Workshop in Drammen part 2 of 2.mkv" -strict normal  -c:a aac -q:a 0.9   -vf "hwupload=e
xtra_hw_frames=128,vpp_qsv=w=1696:h=954"  -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryslow -q:v 32 -movflags +faststart  "VP9 test.mp4"
Routing option err_detect to both codec and muxer layer
Routing option strict to both codec and muxer layer
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 00000000003e9500] Using D3D9Ex device.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 00000000003e9300] Initialize MFX session: API version is 1.34, implementation version is 1.11
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'vp9_input_file.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 02:30:37.56, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 17668 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), 1 reference frame, yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 02:30:37.535000000
    Side data:
      stereo3d: 2D
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, delay 312 (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 02:30:37.561000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (vp9_qsv) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0000000000431b80] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0000000000413900] Using D3D9Ex device.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0000000000413880] Initialize MFX session: API version is 1.34, implementation version is 1.11
[vp9_qsv @ 0000000002cbc780] Decoder: output is video memory surface
[vp9_qsv @ 0000000002cbc780] Could not load the requested plugin 'a922394d8d87452f878c51f2fc9b4131': specified object was not found (-9)
[vp9_qsv @ 0000000002cbc780] Error loading plugins
[vp9_qsv @ 0000000002cbc780] Error initializing an MFX session
[vp9_qsv @ 0000000002cbc780] Error initializing the MFX video decoder: invalid handle (-6)
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
[vp9_qsv @ 0000000002cbc780] Decoder: output is video memory surface
[vp9_qsv @ 0000000002cbc780] Could not load the requested plugin 'a922394d8d87452f878c51f2fc9b4131': specified object was not found (-9)
[vp9_qsv @ 0000000002cbc780] Error loading plugins
[vp9_qsv @ 0000000002cbc780] Error initializing an MFX session
[vp9_qsv @ 0000000002cbc780] Error initializing the MFX video decoder: invalid handle (-6)
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
[vp9_qsv @ 0000000002cbc780] Decoder: output is video memory surface
```

I have the newest driver from Intel, all non-qsv commands I've tried work, h264_qsv works as both a decoder and encoder, and I've tried this on two Windows 7 systems and one Windows 10 system, all with different Intel processors, and I get the same results.  I've seen many postings at various sites where people ask about this, but I have not seen an answer.

Can anyone please explain why ffmpeg is not "loading the requested plugin"? Is there some sort of problem with the QSV software that Intel isn't talking about?

Or perhaps I should ask a more basic question.  Has anyone here actually been able to actually use the hevc_qsv or vp9_qsv codecs successfully for decode or encode on any Windows 7 system?  I see lots of questions, but I have not seen anyone post an example that says "this actually works when I tested it on my system".  All I see is theoretical code that "should work".  Should I keep trying to solve this problem, or is the Intel supplied software faulty, and is never going to work?

Comment: a) does your CPU support it?  
b) you're using v4.4, have you tried with v6.0?

Comment: My CPU should support it, according to the Intel web page.  I have also tried 6.0, but the only builds I can find don't appear to support QSV at all.  If you could specify the location where I can download a built version of 6.0 that has full QSV support it would be very helpful.

Comment: You're using my 4.4 build. Get my 6.0 build from https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/

Comment: I went to your web site, scrolled through the maze of options, decided that ffmpeg-6.0-full_build.7z was probably the file I needed, downloaded it, renamed ffmpeg.exe to 60mpeg.exe so I could keep the old and new builds in the same place and test them both under the same conditions.  What happened is in the next comment because it's too large to put in a single comment.

Comment: ````60mpeg -err_detect ignore_err -loglevel info -benchmark  -init_hw_device qsv:hw,child_device_type=qsv -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -ec deblock  -t
o 00:05:00.000 -i "DJ2shows09Jun15.avi.mp4"  -strict normal -c:a copy  -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryslow -q:v 30  "ffmpeg 6.0 test.mp4"[AVHWDeviceContext @ 000000000050a500] No supported child device type is enabled
Device creation failed: -40.
Failed to set value 'qsv:hw,child_device_type=qsv' for option 'init_hw_device': Function not implemented
Error parsing global options: Function not implemented
bench: maxrss=19200kB
````

Comment: Are you sure this build includes QSV?  I've never seen this error using 4.4 or earlier versions of ffmpeg that were built with QSV support.

Comment: Also please note the input file I'm tested with is H264 / AVC, just to do a basic test. I haven't tried your 6.0 build with VP9 yet.